# When opening another tab part of the page goes empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you open-up this page and right click any menu items and click "open link in a new tab" nothing will happen, page will remain same as it is. But, if you click with your mouse wheel to open it up in a new tab gallery goes away. This extraordinary error is shocking. Any idea how I can fix it or why it's doing this ?

Link to page; http://goo.gl/kfjlJ

Basically; I keep changing display property of gallery div, and that's how I make this page work with this code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){

    $('a').click(function() {
      $('.gallery').hide();
      $('#' + $(this).data('gallery')).show();
    });
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you rolling this back? What does this question have to do with CSS3?

Comment: I have never seen something like this. Therefore, I am not sure what it would cause page to act like this. I don't know if problem is caused by CSS3 or HTML or JavaScript or something else ?

Comment: your links are: "void(0)", what do you want to see when you open that in a new tab???

Comment: Right click anything on left list and click "open link in a new tab", it will work just fine. But if you click with scroll wheel on any item in the menu gallery disappears. My question is how can I fix this behavior ?