# Changing color of gallery that is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently working on a gallery design. There are 2 Divs on the page. Left div is a list of galleries and right is gallery view. Based on the one you click on left list visible gallery changes on the right with JavaScript. When any gallery opens up from left list it should be blue in the list. If you open up another gallery it should be black again and the one that is just opened should be blue.

How can I achieve my goal ? Can I change colors of list elements with JavaScript ?

Here is my gallery; http://goo.gl/kfjlJ

JavaScript code that hides galleries and shows them.

```
$(window).load(function(){

$('a').click(function() {
  $('.gallery').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).data('gallery')).show();
});
});
```

Comment: And why did you [repost this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607794/when-opening-another-tab-part-of-the-page-goes-empty)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's asume that the list has this format

```
<ul id="list-name">
  <li><a>One</a></li>
  <li><a>Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

ok? you can do this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('.gallery').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data('gallery')).show();
    $('#list-name li.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

So, you just have to create the css class "#list-name li.active" to give the active gallery the color that you want.

Did I understood your problem right?